# Issue with cancelling the selection of txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import a txt file to excel using a button.
I have a dialog box to pick a folder name and display the name of the folder that the user selects.

If the user selects cancel an error occure because of type mismatch. I have declared variables as VARIANT

Have a look in the code:

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
    If txtfilesToOpen = "False" Then
            Exit Sub
    End If
        For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
                ' FINDS EXISTING WORKSHEET
                For Each xlsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If xlsheet.Name = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "") Then
                        xlsheet.Activate
                        GoTo ImportData
                    End If
                Next xlsheet

                ' CREATES NEW WORKSHEET IF NOT FOUND
                Set xlsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add( _
                                     After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
                xlsheet.Name = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "")
                xlsheet.Activate
                GoTo ImportData
```

**My question is how can I handle this exception here**

```
If txtfilesToOpen = "False" Then
            Exit Sub
    End If
```

**if the user cancels the selection, while variables are declared as variant.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ignoring all the code after the lines `If txtfilesToOpen = "False" Then Exit Sub`, there's nothing wrong with it, works fine for me. Are you sure your code isn't breaking at another place?

Comment: Also you could probably use a GoTo statement that takes it to the end of the routine, where I assume you have `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: Yes , I am pretty sure it breaks there , and that because of the variable type, it change that why the error occur.

Comment: It's a variant, it's supposed to change. When you click cancel it returns a `Boolean` so your `Variant` becomes a `Boolean`, and VBA can infer `False` from the text string "False" so it works fine. My Excel 2010 does not have an issue running this code so I'm a bit confused as to why yours is failing here unless you're running something earlier?

Comment: Okay , and when you select a txt it will defenitely give you an error in `For each `

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using this auxiliar function will help you out:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim txtfilesToOpen As String
    txtfilesToOpen = GetFile

End Sub
Private Function GetFile() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Text Files to Open"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "No file was picked. Please run the macro again."
            End
        End If
        GetFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

If the user doesn't pick a file, a MsgBox will pop up warning the user and then finishing the whole procedure. Note that this procedure works for only one selected item at a time. If you need to pick more than one, consider using the folder picker.